# Adsense, are clicks counted without payment settings?

Tags: google-adsense

I've just put adsense websites on my website, but I haven't put my payment details in (I don't particularly want to until I know its feasible, and people have clicked the ads)

Are ad clicks counted if payments aren't entered, as in if people do click on ads will it show earnings without payment details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you only have to make the payment settings when you want to be paid. Clicks will be counter without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll receive earnings even though you haven't entered your payment details. Your ad revenue will stay (and build up) in your account until you enter your information.